# Is there a new version of ehcache-core that is part of the latest versions of Ehcache?

Tags: java, caching, version-control, ehcache

I'm trying to figure out if the latest releases of Ehcache (2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.4, 2.7.5, 2.8.0) actually have a new version of ehcache-core or if ehcache-core has not changed since version 2.6.6 as indicated by [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.6.6). 2.6.6 is the latest available from their [amazon download link](http://ehcache.org/downloads/destination?name=ehcache-core-2.6.6-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=ehcache-core-2.6.6-distribution.tar.gz) as well at the ehcache website (found this by replacing the numbers in the amazon download link).

Does anyone have more knowledge? My assumption is that other pieces of the code were updated in 2.7+ besides ehcache-core, and their website is just bad in assuming that each new full-release has a new version of core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After version 2.6, EhCache moved all their "core" stuff to a different module, kinda like how Spring separates modules.  So if you go to [Maven Central and search for `a:ehcache-core`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3Aehcache%2Dcore), you'll see something like:

```
Group ID                  Artifact ID    Latest Version
=======================   ============   ==============
net.sf.ehcache.internal   ehcache-core   2.8.3
net.sf.ehcache            ehcache-core   2.6.9
```

Since after 2.6.9 they moved all the 'core' stuff internally.  This effectively means that if you had a dependency on `ehcache-core`, i.e.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

...then you can upgrade only to 2.6.9 *without having to change your code*.  If you want to use 2.7+, you'll have to modify your code to use their new API.

Answer (score 1):

When I search in maven central it seems there are actually artifacts for ehcache-core with these versions, but they use groupId net.sf.ehcache.internal instead of net.sf.ehcache. 2.6.6 is the latest version using groupId net.sf.ehcache. I'm not sure whether it's wise to user something that is marked "internal".

Unfortunately don't know whether the 2.7.x and 2.8.0 are actual releases, if they're safe to use and why they're "internal".

Comment: It seems that they are actual releases. I'm not real pleased with their dev team, but I got 2.8.0 to work just fine for me. I had to add a <exclusion> in Maven for our use of ehcache-web though. It looks like this now: `<exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>`